# Use theme folder instead of plugins_url

Tags: theme-development

I imagine this is really simple but I can't work it out.  I am trying to add a menu page to the WordPress dashboard through my theme.  I have the following...

```
add_menu_page( 
    'Test', 
    'Test', 
    'manage_options', 
    'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php', 
    '', 
    plugins_url( 'myplugin/image/icon.png' ), 
    6 
);
```

Which works, but I want to use an icon in my themes directory instead of plugin.  How can I alter this to look in there instead?  I have tried using `theme_url` instead but it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not such a function as `theme_url`, if I am not mistaken.

Take look at [`get_template_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Comment: @fightstarr20 Then please mark it as solution...

Answer (score 4):

`get_template_directory_uri()` should be used to get parent theme directory URI.
`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` should be used to get child theme directory URI.

Comment: It's worth noting that `get_stylesheet_` will get the parent, if no child exists.